# Subtyping function parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I am trying to define an abstract class that has operators to compare two instances of the class. When concretizing the class, however, I want the methods to only compare instances of the same type. Something like this

```
abstract class ComparableSuper{
  def <(other: ComparableSuper): Boolean  
  def <=(other: ComparableSuper): Boolean  
  def >(other: ComparableSuper): Boolean
  def >=(other: ComparableSuper): Boolean
}


class Comparable (val a: Int) extends ComparableSuper {
   def <(other: Comparable): Boolean = this.a < other.a
   def >(other: Comparable): Boolean = this.a > other.a
   def <=(other: Comparable): Boolean = this.a <= other.a
   def >=(other: Comparable): Boolean = this.a >= other.a
}
```

Of course this code does not compile because I am not overriding the methods in the abstract class. If I change Comparable to ComparableSuper in the methods, however, I won't have the assurance that the field a is there.

Is there a way I could specify the type of the class in the method signature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend you to look at [Ordering](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html) type class.

I find, that type-class approach to this problem is much better than `Comaprable` way of doing it (where objects, that you want to compare, actually extend `Comparable`).

With type-class approach you will also give you more type-safety and flexibility. You can actually define `Ordering` instances for existing classes (classes that you can't control and change).

---

`Ordering` can be a little bit clumsy to use, but `Ordered` has implicits that will allow you to   write code like this:

```
import math.Ordered._

def isGreater[T : Ordering](a: T, b: T) = a > b
```

So you even don't compromise convenience. (by the way, `Ordered` is equivalent to Java's `Comparable`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ordered seems to be exactly what I needed. And as a bonus I also discovered PartiallyOrdered, which I'll need somewhere else in my code.

Answer (score 2):

In this case using `math.Ordered` or `math.Ordering` is a better idea, but if you do need this pattern, you can use [*F*-bounded polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification):

```
trait Foo[A <: Foo[A]] {
  def f(that: A): Int
}

class Bar(val x: Int) extends Foo[Bar] {
  def f(that: Bar) = this.x - that.x
}
```

There's a bit of syntactic overhead involved in parametrizing the supertype, but it allows you to have methods that require an instance of the same subclass.

Comment: Great. Although Ordered seems to solve the problem at hand, I see where F-bounded polymorphism could be really useful.